# How to hide Resources tab on page translations in TYPO3 6.2

Tags: typo3, backend, fal

How can i hide the BE tab "Resources" in translated page properties?

In TYPO3 6.2 i want to *use the same media resources in page properties for all languages*.

Frontend is done with:

```
$TYPO3_CONF_VARS[’FE’][’pageOverlayFields’] = ‘uid,title,subtitle,nav_title,keywords,description,abstract,author,author_email’;
```

(removed "media")

So any changes on the tab resources in page properties translations are ignored in FE. **To avoid confused editors i want to hide this tab but i don't know how to do this**.

(maybe it would be better to show the tab and the original language resources without the buttons "Add new relation" and "Select & upload files" but this sounds more complicated to me)

thanks for help

Comment: It is really unclear what you're asking, can you improve your question please?

Comment: @ArekvanSchaijk The goal is to hide the field "media" of the page properties, but *only for translations* of the page, not for the original version.

Comment: @Thosh I think you can just disallow the field "media" of the table "alternative page language" (named `pages_language_overlay` in the database), but allow it on the table `pages`. Have not tried it though, so this is not an answer.

Comment: The same question. When i added page header image in original page. It are needed to use the same image for translation pages. But i must to copy images in Page Resources for every translation. It is terrible)